# How to fetch TeamId?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Can someone please confirm if below is the TeamID ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the Team ID. Are you facing any issues?

Comment: Basically I want to fetch the roaster/user profiles. Can you please confirm the exact URL to obtain the same?

Comment: To fetch the list of users you can either use a Bot and [fetch roster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet) or you could use the graph API to fetch [members in a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: I want to fetch userId's of all the users, can you please provide exact URL?

Comment: You cannot fetch all the user profiles with a single Graph call. First you would need to fetch the list of members using the API i mentioned in my previous comment, and then use the id to fetch individual profiles.